# How to compile Geany from source on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, compiling, geany

How can I compile Geany from source and apply the flag `--enable-gtk3`?

I have a HDPI screen, the icons are tiny, and [this issue](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1097) on GitHub recommends compiling from source.

I've downloaded the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/geany/geany.git
```

Per the instructions on the [Geany page on GitHub](https://github.com/geany/geany#installing-from-a-release-tarball), I've installed packages  `automake`, `autoconf`, `libtool`, and `intltool`.

The instructions say to execute the following commands:

```
./configure
make
# (as root, or using sudo)
make install
```

However, I get tripped up on the first step... I do not see an executable file named `configure` in the source tree, and I get the following error:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt `geany-themes` is the same thing as `geany` - shouldn't you be starting from `git clone https://github.com/geany/geany.git` ? You may also need to run `./autogen.sh` to generate the configure script from `configure.ac`

Comment: @steeldriver, OOps!.. I copied the wrong `git clone` command from my terminal window; I fixed the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/geany/geany.git
Cloning into 'geany'...
remote: Counting objects: 59949, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (46/46), done.
remote: Total 59949 (delta 46), reused 13 (delta 10), pack-reused 59893
Receiving objects: 100% (59949/59949), 55.25 MiB | 2.76 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (47843/47843), done.
```

Then

```
$ cd geany && ls
AUTHORS             COMMITTERS    data                geany.gladep      geany.spec.in  m4           po                README.rst  tests
autogen.sh          configure.ac  doc                 geany.nsi.in      HACKING        Makefile.am  README            scintilla   THANKS
ChangeLog           COPYING       geany.desktop.in    geany.pc.in       icons          NEWS         README.I18N       scripts     TODO
ChangeLog.pre-1-22  ctags         geany.exe.manifest  geany_private.rc  INSTALL        plugins      README.Packagers  src
```

so we can see that the cloned repository has a `configure.ac` file, but no `configure`. Referring to the included `README` file:

> Installing from a Git clone
>   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>
> Install Autotools (*automake*, *autoconf* and *libtool*), *intltool*,
>   and the GLib development files **before** running any of the following
>   commands, as well as *rst2html* from Docutils (see above for details).
>   Then, run `./autogen.sh` and then follow the instructions for
>   `installing from a release tarball`_.

so the answer is that we must run `autogen.sh` **first** and then follow the rest of the instructions:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
(as root, or using sudo)
% make install
```

If you don't want the HTML documentation, then (as suggested) replace `./configure` by

```
./configure --disable-html-docs
```

Comment: This worked, although I had use `--enable-gtk3` for both `autogen.sh` and `configure` to avoid a `No package 'gtk+-2.0'` found error. As I mentioned, I need to compile using gtk3, because I have an HDPI screen, and gtk2 does not scale the icons correctly. May be you can add that to your answer to help others. Here's the exact sequence I used: `sudo apt install automake autoconf libtool intltool libgtk-3-dev docutils-common; cd ~/Downloads; git clone https://github.com/geany/geany.git; cd geany; ./autogen.sh --enable-gtk3; ./configure --enable-gtk3; make; sudo make install`

Comment: @PJSingh why not write your own complete answer - and maybe change the question title to something like *How to compile Geany **with gtk3** on 17.10*?

Answer (score 1):

I think really you need newer version of Geany.
It does not matter self-compiled, or compiled by someone other.
In your case you do not use special configure options.

So you can use packages from [Geany-dev PPA](https://launchpad.net/~geany-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=artful):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins
```

This way is better, because of:

1. it did not trash your system (such as contents of `/usr/local`)
2. if newer version released, you will get it with next `apt-get update` + `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I did not know about the ppa. Your justifications make a lot of sense. However, I do need to use the gtk3 version, because I have an HDPI screen, and gtk2 does not scale the icons correctly. Would the pre-compiled version available from the ppa be for gtk2 or gtk3?

Comment: I just tried the `ppa:geany-dev/ppa`; the icons are very tiny.

Comment: I do not know about "Would the pre-compiled version available from the ppa be for gtk2 or gtk3", you can try to [contact Geany-dev team](https://launchpad.net/%7Egeany-dev/+contactuser) about this problem.